# Troubleshooting high time taken to publish event to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Publishing to kafka takes 3 seconds in one of the environment, however we see that, in other environments it takes only 20 milli seconds .
We have done following to troubleshoot this issue:

1. We have run route trace and we dont see an network latency.
2. Analyzed the logs and found following :

```
 2023-01-05T07:26:24.627Z DEBUG 40 --- [ad | producer-5] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Producer clientId=producer-5] Using older server API v7 to send PRODUCE {acks=-1,timeout=30000,partitionSizes=[esd.mob.vocc.datacollector.sampio.plab01.raw-9=464]} with correlation id 1156 to node 46

2023-01-05T07:26:24.627Z TRACE 40 --- [ad | producer-5] o.a.k.c.p.i.Sender                       : [Producer clientId=producer-5] Sent produce request to 46: (type=ProduceRequest, acks=-1, timeout=30000, partitionRecords=({esd.mob.vocc.datacollector.sampio.plab01.raw-9=MemoryRecords(size=464, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=464 cap=464])}), transactionalId=''

2023-01-05T07:26:27.700Z TRACE 40 --- [ad | producer-5] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Producer clientId=producer-5] Completed receive from node 46 for PRODUCE with correlation id 1156, received {responses=[{topic=esd.mob.vocc.datacollector.sampio.plab01.raw,partition_responses=[{partition=9,error_code=0,base_offset=31376,log_append_time=-1,log_start_offset=31001}]}],throttle_time_ms=0}

2023-01-05T07:26:27.700Z TRACE 40 --- [ad | producer-5] o.a.k.c.p.i.Sender                       : [Producer clientId=producer-5] Received produce response from node 46 with correlation id 1156
```

the log clearly states that it takes 3 seconds to publish the message .
We are using below mentioned code .

```java
 CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> sendResultCompletableFuture = kafkaTemplate.send(payloadMsg);

  sendResultCompletableFuture.whenComplete((data, ex) -> {
                if (Objects.nonNull(ex)) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception while publishing message to kafka, {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
                    throw new KafkaConnectorException(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex), topic, message);
                } else {
                    LOGGER.info("Message handle published to kafka successfully for key ::");
                }
            });
```

Please help in troubleshooting this issue further and share thoughts.

Comment: Producers do not send immediately, it buffers events, and `whenComplete` is asynchronous

Comment: default buffer.memory is 33554432 . which means that the producer will wait to post message until buffer memory is reached ? and when the buffer memory is reached the producer will publish one msg at a time ?

Comment: Wrong config. You want to look at `batch.size` and `linger.ms`

Comment: linger.ms is 0 which means the producer won't wait

Comment: Sure, but `CompletableFuture` also does not wait. Your logs only happen `whenComplete`, which may take some time